# Puzzle Game with image like 15-puzzle (Game of fifteen)

Tags: xcode, image, puzzle

I want to produce a game that have in input some photos.
Then the app scompose this photo like in 15-game, and the user must reorder all this pieces only scrolling up/down/left/right.

Someone can help me? :)

Thank You

Comment: Is this an assignment / homework ? :P

Comment: I havo no idea from wich point to start! I need a hint from you

Comment: My hint is `cocos2d`. Start with a game engine.

Comment: ok..then the solution is study to develop a game with cocos2D.. :) i'll try!! thank you shivan Raptor!

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google search for iOS slider puzzle yielded several results. There are quite a few open source project examples of this around the web. Try these 2 for getting started:

http://www.shmoopi.net/development/slider-puzzle-ios-game-tutorial-1/

http://www.iphonegametutorials.com/2010/09/23/cocos2d-game-tutorial-building-a-slide-image-game/

There are other tutorials and sample codes I've seen that also include pulling from the iPhone photo library. Just look around and you'll find them!